# Regex split string preserving quotes

Tags: c#, regex, split

I need to split a string like the one below, based on space as the delimiter. But any space within a quote should be preserved.

```
research library "not available" author:"Bernard Shaw"
```

to

```
research
library
"not available"
author:"Bernard Shaw"
```

I am trying to do this in C Sharp, I have this Regex: `@"(?<="")|\w[\w\s]*(?="")|\w+|""[\w\s]*"""` from another post in SO, which splits the string into

```
research
library
"not available"
author
"Bernard Shaw"
```

which unfortunately does not meet my exact requirements.

I'm looking for any Regex, that would do the trick.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As long as there can be no escaped quoted inside quoted strings, the following should work:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, "(?<=^[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*) (?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

This regex splits on space characters only if they are preceded and followed by an even number of quotes.

The regex without all those escaped quotes, explained:

```
(?<=      # Assert that it's possible to match this before the current position (positive lookbehind):
 ^        # The start of the string
 [^"]*    # Any number of non-quote characters
 (?:      # Match the following group...
  "[^"]*  # a quote, followed by any number of non-quote characters
  "[^"]*  # the same
 )*       # ...zero or more times (so 0, 2, 4, ... quotes will match)
)         # End of lookbehind assertion.
[ ]       # Match a space
(?=       # Assert that it's possible to match this after the current position (positive lookahead):
 (?:      # Match the following group...
  [^"]*"  # see above
  [^"]*"  # see above
 )*       # ...zero or more times.
 [^"]*    # Match any number of non-quote characters
 $        # Match the end of the string
)         # End of lookahead assertion
```

Comment: How to split it with dots, question marks, exclamation marks etc. instead of spaces. I'm trying to get every sentence one by one except inside of quotes. For example: Walked. **Turned back.** But why? **And said "Hello world. Damn this string splitting things!" without a shame.**

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk: That's worthy of its own StackOverflow question - too big to be answered in a comment.

Comment: @TimPietzcker well I don't know why but I asked nearly same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886103/how-to-find-recurring-word-groups-in-text-with-c) and I got too much reaction like "here's not a code writing service" or "it's not clear" so I'm trying my chance in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

C#:

```
Regex.Matches(subject, @"([^\s]*""[^""]+""[^\s]*)|\w+")
```

Regular expression:

```
([^\s]*\"[^\"]+\"[^\s]*)|\w+
```

Comment: Heh, didn't notice Tim's answer. That'll work for splitting, this is for matching.