# Regex split string preserving quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have this exactly specific requirement, [Regex split string preserving quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780728/regex-split-string-preserving-quotes/4780801#4780801)

**but in JavaScript.**

research library "not available" author:"Bernard Shaw"

to

research

library

"not available"

author:"Bernard Shaw"

I guess js does not support positive lookbehind (googled it :) ). I am not able to do it cleanly in js. 
Any help will be really great as am not much aware of regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer the link below :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817646/javascript-split-string-on-space-or-on-quotes-to-array

Comment: i tried that, but it does not fit in the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me. May be you are missing something.

I tried the following code and it worked fine:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = 'single words "fixed string of words"';
    var split_str = str.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g)
    alert(split_str[0]);
    alert(split_str[1]);
    alert(split_str[2]);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i was just testing for research library "not available" author:"Bernard Shaw" (mentioned in question) and its desired o/p - as per the need.

Comment: did you try using the string mentioned in the question ?

Comment: yes, i did. but my requirement is as mentioned in the question.